# Не работает Slick-slider

Tags: html, jquery, slick.js

Всем привет! Не работает Slick slider, уже голову сломал почему.

Вот подключения:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
```

Это перед `</body>`:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__item">1</div>
    <div class="slider__item">2</div>
    <div class="slider__item">3</div>
</div>
```

Вот так инициализирую слайдер:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

В итоге получаю вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я где-то жестко затупил или глаза уже замылились, но не могу найти проблему. Хелп ми)

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно в джава скрипт не работаю. Но в ошибке сказано, что `slick` это не функция, значит попробуйте вызвать `slick` без скобок. Тоесть `$('.slider').slick{ infinite: true, slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 3 };`

Comment: Ну как помогло?

Comment: К сожалению, это не то :( Плюс я всё делал по официальной документации, код почти что скопирован от туда